# How can we take raw input in a single line with a whitespace between them, then convert them into integers and add them to a list?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

My code:

```
number = raw_input().split()
# I can't get a line here to do the trick
a = list()
a.append(number)
```

All I need to do is enter 2 integers in a single line separated by a whitespace. Then enter them as integers in a Python list and then add the elements back into the result variable.

Comment: The given answers are perfect for what you want, but your confusion arises from the difference between `.append()`, which adds an *element* to a list, and `.extend()` which takes a second list as an argument and extends the first one with its content.

Answer (score 5):

This splits everything you enter at whitespace and tries to convert each entry into an integer:

```
 numbers = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
```

This is a list comprehension. It does the same as this code:

```
numbers = []
for x in raw_input().split():
    numbers.append(int(x))
```

The list comprehension is shorter. If you need to handle potential exceptions and your code gets more complicated, the loop might be more suitable.

**Further improvement - Error Handling**

There is always the possibility that the user enters erroneous data.

```
def get_numbers(count=2):
    """Get `count` integers from one line of user input.
    """
    numbers = []
    msg = 'Please enter {} integers separated by space: '.format(count)
    for entry in raw_input(msg).split():
        try:
            numbers.append(int(entry))
        except ValueError:
            print('Found bad value: {}.'.format(entry))
            return get_numbers()
    if len(numbers) != count:
        print('Need to enter exactly {} numbers. '
              'Found: {}.'.format(count, len(numbers)))
        return get_numbers()
    return numbers

my_two_numbers = get_numbers()
```

Comment: it still does not solve the problem. The list gives an output like this and the elements count is not right.

[[1, 2, 3]]
0

Comment: Here is the full code.

`number = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
a = []
a.append(number)
print a
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    print i`

Comment: @blankyash `numbers` is the result already. No need to append to `a`.
You can write `a = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]` if you insist on the name `a`.

Comment: I would add a clause `if x.isidigt()` to handle bad inputs.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, -10 is a valid number so isdigit will not work, the correct way to cast to int is to use a try/except

Comment: Or `map(int, re.findall(r'-?\d+', user_input))`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi "It is easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission.“ Therefore, I prefer `try` and `except`.

Answer (score 3):

You can map to int but any bad input will raise a valueError:

```
numbers = map(int,raw_input().split())
```

A safer approach would be a try/except to catch when the user enters bad input:

```
while True:
     number = raw_input().split()
     try:
         # try casting to int
         numbers = map(int, number) 
         break
     except ValueError:
         # user entered bad input so print message and ask again
         print("Invalid input")
print(numbers) # list of ints
```

That will also allow one number or more than two numbers so if you want  exactly two you need to check the length after splitting.  You also have a list after splitting so a is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid, bad input and forbidden characters I would use regex to search and then cast:

```
valid_integers = map(int, re.findall(r'-?\d+', user_input)) # cast found strs to ints
```